# Работа Generic в java

Tags: java, generics

начал осваивать тему Дженериков и почти сразу наткнулся на проблему - дело в том, что я хочу создать метод, который будет принимать на вход любой List, элементы которого будут типа Object или производными от него, и возвращать этот же list, но с изменёнными местами двух элементов.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList.add(1);
        intList.add(2);

        List<String> StringList = new ArrayList<>();
        StringList.add("first");
        StringList.add("second");

        List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
        charList.add('a');
        charList.add('b');

        test(intList);
        test(StringList);
        test(charList);
    }

    public static void test(List<? extends Object> list)
    {

        var temp = list.get(1);
        list.set(1, list.get(0));
        list.set(0, temp);
    }
}
```

Компилятор ругается на строчки с кодом

```
list.set(1, list.get(0));
list.set(0, temp);
```

В качестве ошибки выводит следующее:

```
Required type:
capture of ? extends Object
Provided:
capture of ? extends Object
```

У меня есть теория, что ошибка выпадает из-за того, что если я, допустим, закидываю в метод лист интов, то, используя list.set я присваиваю туда Object, что на выходе может повлечь неверный результат. В этом и заключается ошибка? И если да, то как преобразовать код, чтоб я мог подавать любой лист и менять в нём два элемента местами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто:

```
public static <K> List<K> test(List<K> list) {
    K temp = list.get(1);
    list.set(1, list.get(0));
    list.set(0, temp);
    return list;
}
```